# How to get the ip range out of a CIDR Notation or an address netmask pair using Java

Tags: java, ip, netmask

For example:
How to get the lower-higher ip address of the CIDR Notation 10.66.114.0/24 
In this case the answer is:
10.66.114.1 - 10.66.114.254

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942299/converting-cidr-address-to-subnet-mask-and-network-address

Comment: And your example is wrong. It is 10.66.114.0 - 10.66.114.255

Answer (score 4):

Here's the gist of it (I'm a C guy):

```
unsigned int network = 0x0a427200; /* 10.66.114.0 */
unsigned int subnet_length = 24;

unsigned int mask = 0xfffffff << (32 - subnet_length);
unsigned int bcast = 0xffffffff >> (32 - subnet_length);

unsigned int start_ip = (network & mask) + 1;
unsigned int end_ip = (network & mask) + (bcast - 1);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <ncurses.h>
// ncurses.h includes stdio.h
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// determine network range of masked ip. eg: 192.168.113.0/25
// unsigned int network = 0x0a427200; /* 10.66.114.0 */
// unsigned int subnet_length = 24;
// 
// unsigned int mask = 0xfffffff << (32 - subnet_length);
// unsigned int bcast = 0xffffffff >> (32 - subnet_length);
// 
// unsigned int start_ip = (network & mask) + 1;
// unsigned int end_ip = (network & mask) + (bcast - 1);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
//  char arg[50] = " ";
    char ipmask[50] = "192.168.113.0/25";
// determine network range of masked ip. eg: 192.168.113.0/25
    unsigned int network = 0xc0a87100; /* 192.168.113.0 */
    unsigned int subnet_length = 25;

    unsigned int mask = 0xfffffff << (32 - subnet_length);
    unsigned int bcast = 0xffffffff >> (subnet_length);
//   unsigned int bcast = 0xffffffff >> (32 - subnet_length);

    unsigned int start_ip = (network & mask) + 1;
    unsigned int end_ip = (network & mask) + (bcast);

    initscr();
    cbreak();
    printw("\nipmask %s\nstart %x end %x range %x\n"
      "press any key\n", ipmask, start_ip, end_ip, end_ip - start_ip + 1);

    getch();
    endwin(); // close ncurses library and restores previous console
    return(0);

}
/*****************************************************************************/
// end netmask

    gcc -Wall netmask.c -o netmask -lm -lncurses
```