# How can I detect if an IP is in a network?

Tags: java, ip

I found in python (`lib ipaddress`). It`s python example.

```
ip="1.232.12.3"
net="1.232.12.0/20"
ip in net
```

result `true`

Can I find this in Java?

Comment: Try taking a look at [InetAddress#isReachable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable%28int%29)

Comment: you should write this as an answer, so question this is marked as answered from the outside :)

Comment: `isReachable()` does not tell if an IP address is in the same network,  it does just some kind of ping to a possibly remote node.

Comment: Maybe this one helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942299/converting-cidr-address-to-subnet-mask-and-network-address

Answer (score 7):

What you're asking is if an IP is in a given *cidr range*. You could write your own code to figure out the start and end of the cidr and see if the IP falls in that range, or just use the [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) library.

The [SubnetUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/net/util/SubnetUtils.html) class does exactly what you want:

```
String cidrRange = "1.232.12.0/20";
String addr = "1.232.12.3";
SubnetUtils utils = new SubnetUtils(cidrRange);
boolean isInRange = utils.getInfo().isInRange(addr);
```